# Bitmap loading very slow

Tags: android

I'm using this method for loading albumArt in list

```
 long thisAlbum = musicCursor.getLong(albumColumn);

          Bitmap artWork = null;

            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                    .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, thisAlbum);

            try {
                artWork = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        musicResolver, albumArtUri);
                artWork = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(artWork, 150, 150, true);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                artWork = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.no_cover);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            songsList.add(new Songs(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, artWork));
        }
```

everything is working fine but when i open my activity it takes more then 10 seconds to load the activity and when i remove this bunch of code activity open as normally ,can anyone tell me please why it is happening and please tell me also what to do or any update for code

Comment: Load your album art in a background thread. Consider replacing all of this code with an image-loading library (e.g., Picasso) so you can load the album art on demand rather than all up front.

Comment: I'm beginner  I've no idea how to upgrade this code can you please suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of Bitmap I always use glide library(It gives smoothness to app)**

**So just add it in build.gradle(Module App)**

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
```

**code to load image in imageview using glide**

```
 Glide.with(context).load(imagePath).crossFade().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).thumbnail(0.5f).into(imageView);
```

> I Hope It will Help You :)

Comment: thanks for answering ,what to put in image path or in imageView

Comment: Glide can load images in all formats so imagePath can be String, Uri, File, Integer and URL

Comment: if I'd use this so wouldn't need of asynTask ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make the bitmap from the images from your phone.

I think the images in your phone are too large.

You can use Glide to make Bitmap for your local image.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
.load(new File(pictureUri.getPath())) // Uri of the picture
.asBitmap().
    into(100, 100). // Width and height
    get();
```

Remember to run this code within AsyncTask or Thread.

Hope it will helpfull to you.